# Should we edit answers that suggest OP ask ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion, edits, chatgpt

Every once in a while I see an answer that suggests OP asks ChatGPT. If it is effectively just a comment telling the OP to ask ChatGPT, then I downvote and flag accordingly, but what should I do if there is a legit answer but includes a plea for OP to ask ChatGPT too?

I can see it three ways:

- Asking ChatGPT is *technically* a *somewhat possibly* useful tidbit (if we forget about the temporary ban), so it might not be needed to remove it. Almost like a link to another article on the topic, except it is written by a bot and not a human.
- On the other hand, ChatGPT answers are banned, so are they banned in all parts of the question? If so, then it should just be edited out.
- Lastly, it might raise suspicion that the author used ChatGPT to write/help with their answer, so it might be better to not edit and flag for moderators instead.

So what should I do when I come across an answer telling OP to ask ChatGPT: leave it, edit it, or flag it and leave?

Comment: Is there anything else in the answer, other than to suggest that they ask ChatGPT? If not, flag the answer as not an answer.

Comment: *Asking ChatGPT is technically a somewhat possibly useful tidbit"* Many would dispute this.

Comment: Ask *Chat* what to do.

Comment: I assume [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714011/2821954). Too much fluff in my opinion, but removing them and leaving the 1st sentence will still be an answer, however low-quality it is.

Comment: This probably depends strongly on the Q&A. I've seen advice to use ChatGPT to create Regex from requirements and can actually see that working as a transformative process. But using ChatGPT as effectively a search engine for data that *isn't* in the conversion... *shudders*

Comment: "So what should I do when I come across an answer telling OP to ask ChatGPT" - An answer suggesting somebody Google for their answer would not be acceptable, so an answer suggesting to use ChatGPT, should also be unacceptable. In my experience it takes the knowledge to answer your own question, to train ChatGPT to generate an answer, that would actually be considered accurate and proper.

Comment: Let's re-frame: `s/ChatGPT/Google/g` - would that be appropriate, either? I don't think so. If SO is to be a knowledge base, then "Your knowledge is in another castle" doesn't seem to fit that role.

Comment: For the post @AndrewT. links, the suggested edit seems more than appropriate; it appropriately removes any of the noise, think includes things like the "welcome" text as well as the suggestion to use ChatGPT.

Comment: That the answer is *wrong* is a moot/irrelevant point, in my opinion, @MisterMiyagi ; would you be of a different opinion if the answer was correct? The question here isn't asking about the "correctness" of an answer, but the recommendation of ChatGPT in an answer.

Comment: The recommendation of ChatGPT, Google, or RTFM are the same type of answers, pointless dribble that should be downvoted and deleted, and potentially suspending the author of such an answer that made such a recommendation. Those type of answers, are worse than the signposts that get submitted in my opinion, which are also worthy of a downvote.

Comment: I think you're mixing things up here, @MisterMiyagi . The "polishing a turd" thing is more about when you edit an answer that's still *bad* and shouldn't exist. For example, a post that contains malformed links, which was mean to be a link only answer; taking the time to correct the broken markdown is "polishing a turd". There's a big difference between a *wrong* answer (gives incorrect advice or a non-working solution) and a "turd".

Comment: *"But removing it from that answer sill leaves plenty of incorrect advice"* that is irrelevant to the question here.

Comment: If ChatGPT is useful here, then certainly Google is better. LMGTFY was banned years ago.

Answer (score 30):

At best suggesting that the question OP uses ChatGPT to try and get answers is noise. At worst it's bad advice; ChatGPT/OpenAI is good at writing *convincing* text but **does not** have a good history of providing *correct* text. Either way, it doesn't belong in an answer.

If you see an answer that effectively just suggests that the question OP asks ChatGPT then flag it as not an answer. You may wish to downvote the answer too.

If the answer also includes an answer then editing to remove the noise, along with correcting other things you see fit (spelling, grammar, formatting, etc) would be a good edit. You should also, again, consider voting appropriately.

If you are concerned that the post may be generated by OpenAI/ChatGPT, then raise a custom mod flag. Explain why you feel that it is ChatGPT generated in your mod flag (perhaps the recommendation of using ChatGPT along with perfect grammar makes you concerned). If the content *was* generated by ChatGPT, then a moderator will take the appropriate action.

Comment: (Right under the prompt input, but in a smaller font, the web interface to ChatGPT includes *"ChatGPT may produce inaccurate information about people, places, or facts."*. I don't know if that was the case at the time.)

Answer (score 11):

Editing the answer suggests that there's some portion of the answer that is salvageable.

If that's the case, then I don't *think* I have that much of an issue with you editing out that portion of the post.  Keeping the relevant information in and editing noise out is a pretty normal convention.

But if the post is really *just* a plug/recommendation for ChatGPT, I'd say downvote and flag as "not an answer".

It may be worth keeping a loose eye out; if you think that the answer was generated (even in part) by ChatGPT, that's independently worth a flag for moderator intervention.